# Passing my ViewModel to View and getting single data

Tags: c#, list, entity, viewmodel, ienumerable

My ViewModel looks that:

```
public class WerehouseViewModel
{
    public Werehouse Werehouse { get; set; }
    public WerehouseKey WerehouseKey { get; set; }
}
```

That's how I get data from database

```
var viewModel =
             from Wh in db.Werehouses
             join WhK in db.WerehouseKeys on Wh.WhID equals WhK.WhID
             where Wh.WhID == id
             select new WerehouseViewModel { Werehouse = Wh, WerehouseKey = WhK };
return View(viewModel);
```

I know I have to use IEnumerable type to show in my View, but I would like to show only one Werehouse (and only one is in view model) and Keys (let's say that there are three keys for one werehouse). How can I show one Werehouse in list and below all keys in table? Because when I use

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    <div>@x.Werehouse.Kod_magazynu</div>
    <div>@x.Werehouse.Ulica</div>
    <div>@x.Werehouse.Numer_magazynu</div>
    <div>@x.Werehouse.Miasto</div>
}
```

It shows 3 times same data.

Comment: Because you have 3 keys for this warehouse in the database ? What do you want to do in this case ? Take the first one ?

Comment: I want to show data of one Werehouse once, not three times and data of three keys of this Werehouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first warehouse only from your model:

```
@{
   var warehouse = Model.Select(x=> x.Werehouse).FirstOrDefault();

   <div>@warehouse.Kod_magazynu</div>
   <div>@warehouse.Ulica</div>
   <div>@warehouse.Numer_magazynu</div>
   <div>@warehouse.Miasto</div>
}
```

Then you can loop to show the keys:

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    <div>@x.WerehouseKey.SomeProperty</div>
}
```

Comment: All I need to do is to write what you wrote in View? Seems the line "var warehouse(...)" doesn't work even with @. I'm new in MVC, sorry :<

Comment: Ah ok nevermind, you edited it and added @{ (...) } . Now it works, thanks :)